# how to do math operations on a pandas columns and save it as a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
                  a          b           c
6/29/2018   0.744189037 0.251833984 0.632784618
6/30/2018   0.476601558 0.694181607 0.7951655
7/1/2018    0.91376258  0.111712256 0.813708374
7/2/2018    0.849505199 0.037035716 0.973137932
```

So I am trying to use this data frame and create a new one based off of math operations. So far I have `df3 = df2[['a','b']] and df4 = pd.DataFrame(df3[['a']]*2 - df3[['b']])`.

To summarize, I want to use df3 and multiple column a by 2 and subtract that value by column b and put the result into a brand new data frame.

The final output that I would want to get too would be

```
               2*a-b
6/29/2018   1.23654409
6/30/2018   0.259021508
7/1/2018    1.715812903
7/2/2018    1.661974683
```

However this yields all values of `NA`.

Comment: Your question as you have it written now is unreadable. Please edit the formatting and provide a minimum working example so we can help you.

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve? Can you tell in words what the math operation does? Also, can you post the expected output?

Comment: wanna do b^2 - a?

Comment: hey i apologize for the bad format, new to stack exchange. I am trying to multiply column a by 2 and subtract by column b and put it into an independent data frame by itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If need use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) with [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), last [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df['a'].mul(2).sub(df['b']).to_frame('col')
#same as
#df1 = (df['a'] * 2 - df['b']).to_frame('col')
print (df1)
                col
6/29/2018  1.236544
6/30/2018  0.259022
7/1/2018   1.715813
7/2/2018   1.661975
```

And for `Series`:

```
s = df['a'].mul(2).sub(df['b'])
print (s)
6/29/2018    1.236544
6/30/2018    0.259022
7/1/2018     1.715813
7/2/2018     1.661975
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am recieving  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame' when I type that. Perhaps its an issue of my typing df1[['2043-08-31']].mul(2) as opposed to typing df.a

Comment: Need only one [] like `df1['2043-08-31'].mul(2)`

Comment: @Victor - Thank you, nice day!

Answer (score 3):

ind_df = df['col_a'].apply(lambda x: x*2) - df[col_b']

Comment: Rather not, because `apply` are loops under the hoods, so slow.