# How do I get the difference between earliest and latest date & timestamp for a car maintenance using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want the data based on the TRIP ID, start is when the car gets into service and end is when it leaves. There are both date and timestamp columns.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247928/how-to-do-math-operations-on-a-pandas-columns-and-save-it-as-a-new-dataframe look at this thread... may be help there??

Comment: Don't use image, use only plain text data. Thanks

Comment: got it, will do in the future

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
max = DataFrame.max(axis=NoDefault.no_default, skipna=True, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)
```

(and similarly `min` for the minimum value).

the reference code is here:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html